# .NET NetworkStream.EndWrite() bytes written

Tags: .net, tcpclient, networkstream

The MSDN documentation clearly states that:

> After obtaining the NetworkStream, you can call the EndWrite method to
>   successfully complete the send operation **and return the number of
>   bytes sent.**

Emphasis mine.

However, it returns nothing (void):

```
public override void EndWrite(
    IAsyncResult asyncResult
)
```

Am I missing something, or is this a typo (`EndRead()` does return bytes read).?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not missing anything, it is a doc bug.  Probably induced by copy/pasting the EndRead article.  Where it very much does matter.  You already know how many bytes were written, all of them.

Comment: So, aside from following the standard pattern, why call EndWrite()? Is it really necessary?

Comment: Yes, essential to clean-up resources and to find out whether the read actually finished without errors.